# Sorting dropdown (filled with dictionaries) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sorting, select

I have an items which is a 2-d dictionary : 
Basically each element is of the following form :

```
{'key': {'count': value}}
```

I would like to sort my dropdown using this count :

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="k for (k,v) in items | orderBy:'v.count'"></select>
```

Unfortunately, what I tried above is not working (it doesn't sort) and I am not sure how to do so.

Thanks

Comment: It simply doesn't get sorted. (I don't see any error though).

Comment: show the full data items

Comment: items : {4: {description: 'foo', count:2}, 3: {description: 'foo', count:1}, 8: {description: 'foo', count:7}}